# c++ templating to specific type without using traditional Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T_>
class my_class {
public:
       typedef T_   value_type;
       typedef T_ * pointer;
```

I'm developing a templated class, however because the C++ error detection and intellisence suck for templated stuff, is there a way I can set the template to example int to get the benefit of intellisence, and then when I'm done development just switch it back and fix a couple errors?

I still want my code to be generic and re-writing it as Template Specialization is too much work.

I want to be able to do something like

```
template <typename T_ = int>
class my_class {
public:
       typedef T_   value_type;
       typedef T_ * pointer;
```

Comment: Updating your Visual Studio should help, I have no problem with templates and Intellisense using 2010

Comment: @dauphic Running VS2010 ultimate latest updates

Comment: The code you wrote under "I want to be able to do something like" is perfectly valid, so why don't you use that?

Comment: @interjay I previously tried it, yes it does compile but it doesn't fix the issue I'm having and I can still override that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but you could typedef `T_` to `int` in the class and disable the template statement, either through the pre-processor or commenting it out.

```
#ifndef NO_MY_CLASS_TEMPLATE
template <typename T_ = int>
#endif
class my_class {
#ifdef NO_MY_CLASS_TEMPLATE
       typedef int T_;
#endif
public:
       typedef T_   value_type;
       typedef T_ * pointer;
```

Comment: Sort of.  This has significant implications for dependent type resolution however.

Comment: This looks good and seems to be working, I have to do some more work before I can verify it though, will accept as answer and +1 then

Comment: Sweet thanks, this exposed several dozen errors I had that I couldn't even see before cause the templating hid them